# Moving files on NTFS reveals multiple conflicting versions

Tags: windows, ntfs

I just want to understand how this could have happened, apologies if this is not the correct question format.

I tried moving a large folder from one NTFS partition to another. The process was briefly interrupted and upon retrying, I was prompted about some files which already existed in the destination, and which one(s) I would like to keep. Curiously, the pairs had the same timestamps, but different sizes, and neither version is corrupt, just different versions of the same file. I don't remember when these versions came about, but how could both of them have existed in the same path in the source, only to result in a conflict when moved? Is this due to 'Alternate Data Streams' in NTFS?

[image: Replace or Skip files]

Example diff:

[image: WinMerge diff]

No recent processes had any of these files open, and they are not in source control either.

I was also prompted about certain files/folders no longer existing in the source directory, and these had already gotten moved.

Comment: I have seen this since windows 7 and have never found an explanation for this behavior.

Comment: __certain files/folders no longer existing__  That one I have never seen before, I would be running, from PowerShell : __fsutil resource setautoreset true c:__ _to clean the transactional metadata on the next mount on drive C_  and then __chkdsk /F__ and then rebooting... I would be at a small panic.